# Manufacturing of Translucent LED Indicating Symbols (e.g. router indicator lights)

Tags: led, light, manufacturing, enclosure, indicator

I've been researching how manufacturers create custom LED-illuminated symbols such as those seen on the router in the image below:
[image: led_indicator_router]

I haven't been able to find any information online from custom enclosure manufacturer websites or discussion websites such as this. I found a somewhat related thread in the 3dprinting Stack Exchange but it never led to any real conclusion on the generally accepted method of creating these LED effects ([LED Indicators with 3D Printer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/2612/3d-printing-enclosure-with-led-indication-symbols-is-this-possible)).

Based on my observations of these physical products, my best guess is that they are using some type of translucent material, possibly tinted acrylic, and using some method to print the negative symbol shape on the back side of the acrylic. Then a light pipe or direct LED lighting can be used to illuminate each symbol.

Could anyone confirm if this is the method that is used? If so does anyone have more details on specific materials, printing processes, and manufacturers which can provide this service?

Thank you all for your consideration.

Comment: In my limited expereince we've always printed on some transparent plastic with some opaque ink, leaving the symbol for the light to shine through. Then, depending on various mechanical requirements, we either have the LED behind the screen directly or use a light pipe.

Comment: Awesome, that was more or less what I suspected was the case. Do you know what method you used for printing? Was it screenprinted or directly printed onto the material? Thanks!

Comment: "How do I print opaque ink on transparent plastic?" probably should be asked somewhere else. Your new question doesn't have anything to do with electronics design.

Comment: having busted lots of devices apart, these shadow mask look to be printed on an overhead transparency, or something akin to it.

Comment: Brother P-Touch printers can print on a clear label with black text. You can fudge clear on black (for not the full tape width).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about electrical engineering.

Comment: It's basically a type of printed label if it contains no electrical component. Many companies can supply it. You provide the artwork and the specifications. You need to consider fire-retardant properties and perhaps insulation properties. Companies that make membrane keyboards can do it too, but it will likely be rather dear.

Answer (score 1):

> Based on my observations of these physical products, my best guess is that they are using some type of translucent material, possibly tinted acrylic, and using some method to print the negative symbol shape on the back side of the acrylic. Then a light pipe or direct LED lighting can be used to illuminate each symbol.
>
> Could anyone confirm if this is the method that is used? If so does anyone have more details on specific materials, printing processes, and manufacturers which can provide this service?

Yes, the light is fed in through a tube and the area where the light is desired to be emitted is clear, while the area where light is not desired to emit is opaque.
[image]
[image]